# How can i check of a string contains a letter space letter space and anotherl letter C#

Tags: c#, game-engine

I need help to check if a string contains a word like: P I E T S N O T . C O M

I don't want it to say true when I have it like this: "Hi my name is" etc., 
only if it is 1 letter space 1 letter and that 3 times or more in a string. This is for my game's banfilter.
I dont want that peaple can say Hi come to my game H I H I H I . C O M

I can't figure it out because I don't want to add all the combinations for 1 word.

Comment: I think this question is perfectly legit...

Comment: Can you show what you have tried and explain what is not working?

Comment: show sample inputs and expected outputs to make it more **clear**.

Comment: I had edited your question, but on second thought I probably misunderstood so I've reverted the edit. If it was correct after all, please reapply the edit.

Comment: No i dont want that this is P I E T S N O T . C O M true<<
That must be false 
this: Hi my name is must be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly following your requirement, everything that is not a letter followed by a space and repeat the sequence until the end of the string

```
void Main()
{
    string test = "P I E T S N O T . C O M";
    Console.WriteLine(CheckSpaceLetterSequence(test));
    test = "Hi my name is";
    Console.WriteLine(CheckSpaceLetterSequence(test));
}


bool CheckSpaceLetterSequence(string test)
{
    int count = 0;
    bool isSpace = (test[0] == ' ');
    for(int x = 1; x < test.ToCharArray().Length; x++)
    {
        bool curSpace = (test[x] == ' ');
        if(curSpace == isSpace)
            return false;

        isSpace = !isSpace;
        count++;
        if(count == 3)
           break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
bool allLetterSpace = text.Trim().Length >= 6 && text.Trim()
   .Select((c, i) => new { IsWhiteSpace= Char.IsWhiteSpace(c), Index = i })
   .All(x => x.Index % 2 == 1 ? x.IsWhiteSpace : !x.IsWhiteSpace);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string word = "Hello, my name is f i s h b i s c u i t s";

if (word.Replace(" ", "").Contains("fishbiscuits"))
{
 // code here
}
```

Comment: How does this work for Hi, my name is fishbiscuits? Also, contains won't compile.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't meet the requirements - "only if it is 1 letter space 1 letter and that 3 times or more in a string"

Comment: I agree it doesn't, but it sounds like a false requirement, so I've provided my solution as a way to solve the generalised problem.

Comment: This answer does not explain how it solves the problem. It is a blob of code.

Comment: I it also possible to check of it conatains letter whitespace letter whitespace... because you need to add now all words that must be banned..

Answer (score 0):

This will tell you if every other character in `text` is a space:

```
bool spaced = text.Select((c,i) => (c == ' ') == (i % 2 == 1)).All(b => b);
```

Answer (score 0):

A Regular expression solution could look like this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<name>(?:[A-Z.] ){2,}[A-Z.])");
Match m = regex.Match("P I E T S N O T . C O M");
if (m.Success)
    MessageDlg.Show("Name is " + m.Groups["name"].Value);
else
    MessageDlg.Show("No name found");
```

If you need it to match more letters than capital letters and dot, you should extend the two [A-Z.] to e.g. [A-Za-z0-9.,-_].